# How to read continuous log file from last read line | Linux Shell

Tags: linux, awk, jmeter, logfile-analysis

***Platform***: RHEL7

***Situation***:

- A JMeter report file is being appended with new results every 5 minutes by crontab script
- Another awk script looks for response time greater than 500ms and sends email alerts

***Problem Statement***:

- The requirement is to scan only newly added lines in the report file.
  Presently, the awk script is reading the complete report every time
  and sends alerts even for older events. *awk -F "," '$4 != 200 || $14>
  500' results.jtl*
- *Good-to-Have* if the awk script can read from the end of the file up to line read last time. This shall help in creating an alert for the latest event first.

Any suggestion shall be a great help.

Comment: Have you used `tail -f` command?

Comment: Let's try this.  `tail -f results.jtl | awk -F "," '$4 != 200 || $14> 500'`

Comment: @tkhm I would think that since the script is scheduled in cron and runs periodically, _italic_tail -f_italic_ command may not work.

Comment: Does the log file ever get truncated to remove the oldest lines or does it just keep growing forever (hint: it can't so how is that avoided?)? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason for not using:

- [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion): for failing samples which response times are over 500 ms
- [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller):  with condition `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` which checks whether last sampler is successful or not
- [SMTP Request Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter): to send an email when there is a failure